# create point in graph using xslwriter

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

[image]

I am able to generate graph using `xlsxwriter` in Python by line properties. But I need to put
4 dots(diamond) on the particular value. Can anyone suggest me How Can I put diamond on the particular value using line properties in `xlsxwriter`.

if require than I can post the code also.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook
import math
def graph(headline,table_percentage,table_threashold):
    """Create Graph Chart"""
    wb = load_workbook(filename = 'sample.xlsx')
    worksheet_final = wb.get_sheet_by_name(name='test')
    workbook = Workbook('graphs.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    heading =['test1','test2','test3','test4','test5']
    worksheet.write_row('A1',heading)
    count =2
    while(count < worksheet_final.get_highest_row()):
        data_x = worksheet_final.cell(row = count, column = 1).value
        data_y = worksheet_final.cell(row = count, column = 2).value
        data_s1 = worksheet_final.cell(row = count, column = 8).value
        data_d0 = worksheet_final.cell(row = count, column = 14).value
        data_d1 = worksheet_final.cell(row = count, column = 20).value
        worksheet.write(count,0,round(data_x,0))
        worksheet.write(count,1,data_y)
        worksheet.write(count,2,data_s1)
        worksheet.write(count,3,data_d0)
        worksheet.write(count,4,data_d1)
        count = count + 1
    # Create a new chart with properties object.
    chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})
    cellname = headline
    chart.set_title({'name':cellname})
    chart.set_x_axis({'name':'CLK-D Time (ps)',
                  'name_font':{'size':14,'bold':True},
                  })
    chart.set_y_axis({'name':'CLK-Q Time (ps)',
                  'name_font':{'size':14,'bold':True},
                  })
    chart.set_size({'width': 720, 'height': 576})

    # Add a series to the chart.
    chart.add_series({
    'categories' : '=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$503',
    'values': '=Sheet1!$B$1:$B$503',
    'name':'clk2q0_S',
    'line':{'color':'blue'},
    })

    chart.add_series({
    'categories' : '=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$503',
    'values': '=Sheet1!$C$1:$C$503',
    'name':'clk2q1_S',
    'line':{'color':'red'}})

    chart.add_series({
    'categories' : '=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$503',
    'values': '=Sheet1!$D$1:$D$503',
    'name':'clk2q0_H',
    'line':{'color':'blue'}})

    chart.add_series({
    'categories' : '=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$503',
    'values': '=Sheet1!$E$1:$E$503',
    'name':'clk2q1_H',
    'line':{'color':'red'}})

   # Insert the chart into the worksheet.
    worksheet.insert_chart('K1', chart)
    workbook.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    table_percentage = "5%"
    table_threashold = {}
    #Need to put dot on the below 4 value
    table_threashold ['setup_mt1'] = [5,210]
    table_threashold ['setup_mt0'] = [-105,140]
    table_threashold ['hold_mt0'] = [-39,143]
    table_threashold ['hold_mt1'] = [-41,96]
    headline = "sample_data"

    graph(headline,table_percentage,table_threashold)
```

Comment: @alecxe, I mean,we need to represent some symbol at particular value. In other words it is represents of threshold level.For Ex: (10.200) we can put some symbol on the line so user can easily identify threshold level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) it isn't possible to turn on individual point markers in a series but it is possible to turn point markers off for a series with markers. To do this you need to use the [points (see docs)](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/working_with_charts.html#chart-series-option-points) series option and turn off markers that you don't want.

```
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

workbook = Workbook('chart_point.xlsx')

worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})

data = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [2, 4, 6, 8, 10],
    [3, 6, 9, 12, 15],

]

# Write the data for the chart.
worksheet.write_column('A1', data[0])
worksheet.write_column('B1', data[1])
worksheet.write_column('C1', data[2])

# Add a chart series with markers but turn some off.
chart.add_series({
    'categories': '=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5',
    'values': '=Sheet1!$B$1:$B$5',
    'marker': {'type': 'automatic'},
    'points': [
            {'fill': {'none': True}, 'line': {'none': True}},
            {'fill': {'none': True}, 'line': {'none': True}},
            {'fill': {'none': True}, 'line': {'none': True}},
            {'fill': {'none': True}, 'line': {'none': True}},
    ],
})

# Add a second chart series.
chart.add_series({
    'categories': '=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5',
    'values': '=Sheet1!$C$1:$C$5',
    'marker': {'type': 'automatic'},
    'points': [
            {'fill': {'none': True}, 'line': {'none': True}},
            {},
            {'fill': {'none': True}, 'line': {'none': True}},
            {'fill': {'none': True}, 'line': {'none': True}},
            {'fill': {'none': True}, 'line': {'none': True}},
    ],
})

worksheet.insert_chart('E9', chart)

workbook.close()
```

[image]

This implies that you can only indicate markers that are part of the series, i.e., there is no facility in XlsxWriter for adding a point to a chart that isn't part of a series.