# create Point in scatter Graph

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I have asked question and got response for putting dot.
[create point in graph using xslwriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16901191/create-point-in-graph-using-xslwriter)

I am trying to add same functionality with the `'type': 'scatter','subtype' : 'straight'` and marker with add series But endup with following options.

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py", line 386, in _store_workbook
    packager._create_package()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\packager.py", line 122, in _create_package
    self._write_chart_files()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\packager.py", line 205, in _write_chart_files
    chart._assemble_xml_file()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\chart.py", line 525, in _assemble_xml_file
    self._write_chart()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\chart.py", line 1158, in _write_chart
    self._write_plot_area()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\chart_scatter.py", line 168, in _write_plot_area
    self._write_chart_type({'primary_axes': 1})
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\chart_scatter.py", line 52, in _write_chart_type
    self._write_scatter_chart(args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\chart_scatter.py", line 91, in _write_scatter_chart
    self._modify_series_formatting()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\chart_scatter.py", line 284, in _modify_series_formatting
    if series['marker'] is None or not series['marker']['defined']:
KeyError: 'defined'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the subtype as `straight_with_markers`.

Try something like this:

```
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'scatter',
                            'subtype': 'straight_with_markers'})
```